# Can we use collection variable as a table in execute immediate select statement?

Tags: oracle, types, collections, oracle11g, execute-immediate

I have written below code.

```sql
Declare
  Type t1 is record (id, type)
  Type t2 is table of t1;
  V_val t2;
Begin
  Select a.id, a.type 
    bulk collect into v_val 
    from table1 a 
   where exits(select 1 from table2 b where a.column = b.column);..
.
.
```

Some code is written here.
If ..
And now I am trying to insert collection variable into 1 table using execute immediate.
Eg.

```sql
Execute immediate 'insert into ' || table || v_column_string ||  ' from' || table|| q'where type =1 and  flag =:1...
```

this is the main statement.
Now I want to concatenate this insert state using my collection variable above something like below

```sql
Execute immediate 'insert into ' || table || v_column_string ||  ' from' || table|| q'where  flag =:1 and exists ( select 1 from table(v_val)y where y.id = id and y.type = type)
```

Using another variable.

Can anyone help me with this?
Tried all the way but no luck...
I am new to plsql coding.
It will be great help .

Comment: Execute immediate ' insert into ' || i.tablename ||  '(' || v_column || ')'  || 'select ' || V_col_rf || ' from ' || i.tablename  || 'r' || 'from table(' || collection Variable|| ')y where y.node = r.node)' using v_rf_flg;   What is wrong in this statement getting wrong number or types of argumenta in call to || error. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance